# Loosing WiFi router connection when moving from one router to another

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I have an issue with my mac book pro (15")

I connect to the WiFi at home but when I take it to my work WiFi it cannot connect.

I get no errors or messages.

Does anybody have any idea what can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, is your computer even seeing the work wifi network? Do you see it in your wifi menu with a lock on it? Or, do you just not see it at all in the wifi menu or in System Preferences/network/wifi?

Comment: It appears in the network list. There is a lock on it, which I know means a password. I have entered this password and it worked fine for a while but a while ago it stopped working. No Idea why. there have been no hardware nor software changes, nor anything to the wifi network.

Comment: Try going through your system prefs wifi history and deleting that network, then re-adding it.

Comment: Network issues arise for a number of reasons so I'm afraid you'll need to give us more details. What year is your macbook, what operating system are you running, what kind of router are you using at work. The more detail, the more likely somebody here will give you the right answer.

Comment: Are you sure the password hasn't changed? Can you connect to it with another device? This sounds like a network issue, not a macbook issue.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by any number of things. Your work may have access restrictions in place which prevent unauthorised devices from connecting. The first place to ask would be your companies IT staff.

Comment: There isn't any IT staff. The network is a basic wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, if possible, would be to connect to the router via ethernet. If there are so few restrictions, you could login to the router's configuration page, find the DHCP config, and reserve the MAC address of your computer to a specific LAN IP. This is *supposed* to happen automatically, but minimally doing this won't hurt. The procedure is different for each router, but [here](http://www.butterscotch.com/tutorial/How-To-Reserve-IP-Addresses-On-Your-Router) is a general tutorial. When you're done, save the changes and logout. Afterwards, you should have no problem connecting to the network.